# Element created within JavaScript adds .type and .disabled attribute but not .form or .value

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

### I am creating an element within JavaScript in a function that is used to populate a `<li>` element.

From the Console I can see that the `<input>` element that I am making is being created, and is being correctly appended to the `<div>` that contains it, but is missing some attributes, namely:

- `form = "day" + dayNumber + "Form"`
- `value = "variableGotFromJsonOject"`

I have debugged using`console.log()` (which can be seen below) to confirm that the above two values do exist, and yet they aren't being given to the element that I am creating.

---

Below is my code snippet:

```
var inputProj = document.createElement("input");
console.log("day" + dayNumber + "Form");
inputProj.form = "day" + dayNumber + "Form";
inputProj.type = "text";
console.log(response.data.data.variables.input.projects.items[0].projectNumber);
inputProj.value = response.data.data.variables.input.projects.items[0].projectNumber;
inputProj.disabled = "disabled";

console.log("inputProj: ");
console.log(inputProj);

proj.appendChild(inputProj);
console.log(proj);
```

---

The output I get from the console is:

```
day4Form
888843
inputProj:
<input type="text" disabled>
<li id="fProjects4"><input type="text" disabled></li>
```

So as can be seen, only the `.type` and `.disabled` attributes are being given to the `<input>` element.

I cannot determine why the `.form` and `.value` attributes aren't being given to the element.

Comment: Did you try "setAttribute" function? Example: "inputProj.setAttribute("type", "text");"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two different kinds of attributes, one of which is a DOM-attribute and the other is a JavaScript object attribute. The following should work:

```
var inputProj = document.createElement("input");
var formAttribute = document.createAttribute("form");
formAttribute.value = "day" + dayNumber + "Form";
inputProj.setAttributeNode(formAttribute);
```

A small quote from this page: https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties.

> In HTML language, tags may have attributes. When the browser reads HTML text and creates DOM objects for tags, it recognizes standard attributes and creates DOM properties from them.
>
> So when an element has id or another standard attribute, the corresponding property gets created. But that doesn’t happen if the attribute is non-standard.

That page contains a lot of interesting and useful information. Worth checking out.

Comment: This is great information. Where could one find more information about what is a DOM attribute, and what is a JS Object attribute?

Comment: I've added a resource to the answer. The entire article is a great read.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `.setAttribute` function?
Example: `inputProj.setAttribute("type", "text");`